# Does GitHub support web notifications?

Tags: github

Similar to [Desktop notifications from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980466/desktop-notifications-from-github) (from 10 years ago) but asking a slightly different question - does GitHub support [web notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)? I'd like to know about comments on my PRs etc but I don't want to install additional software.

**Does GitHub support web notifications? How can I use web notifications with GitHub?**

Answer (score 1):

I use [Notifier for GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/notifier-for-github), a browser extension that sends push notifications. Note that notifications are only sent when the browser is running and the extension is enabled (i.e. not in Incognito, etc.).